# Plant a tree and watch it grow

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art

The trees we are growing have some rules that define how they grow:

### Growth Rules:

1. Trees consist only of branches.
2. Branches are made up of a combination of the following symbols:  `_`, `\`, `|`, `/`, & `_`
3. A tree starts as a single vertical branch/trunk (`|`) on the ground (`_`):

   `__________________|___________________`
4. The food for branch growth comes from light.

   - Light starts at an intensity of 2 at each point in the sky and travels straight down.
   - Each branch is able to eat half the light available to it and the rest passes through to lower branches.
   - Thus, a branch with no other branches above it will get 1 unit of light-food each season, a branch with 1 branch above it will get .5 units of food each season, and in general a branch with n branches over it will get 1/(2^n) units of food each season.
5. At the end of each season, the food is totaled starting with the trunk and moving up and converted into new branches and fruit (apply the following rules until the branch turns into fruit or has less than 1 unit of food remaining):

   - If a branch has less than 1 unit of food at the end of a season, all the food for that branch is stored in that branch until the next season.
   - If a branch has greater than or equal to 1 unit of food and has room to grow, it randomly grows a new branch using the available growth patterns (see below) and stores the remaining food for the next season.
   - If a branch has >= 1 unit of food, nowhere to grow, and has offshoot branches, it evenly distributes the food to its offshoot branches
   - If a branch has >= 1 unit of food, nowhere to grow, and no offshoot branches, it becomes fruit (represented by `O`)
6. Here are the possible growth configurations

Growth Configurations:

```
_    \     |     /   _      _   \   |    /   \    |   /   _ 
 |    |    |    |   |        \   \   \   \   /   /   /   /     __   \_   |_   _|  _/  __
--- Vertical Branches ---      --- Diagonal Branches ---      --- Horizontal Branches ---
```

### Example potential tree:

```
                \  
                /   /
              \/O  |___//
            \_/  \//O\_/ 
              \__/|\|_/
                 \|/
__________________|__________________
```

### Input:

Your program should be able to take as input a list of which snapshots of the tree you would like to see.  For example [10,20,50] would mean you'd like to see the tree after 10 seasons, 20 seasons, and 50 seasons.

### Output:

For each input season, your program should output the season and then a picture of the tree in that season.  If it helps, you can define a maximum age for the tree, such as 60, so that the maximum height for a tree would be 61, and the maximum width would be 121, and then always show the tree on that scale.  Otherwise, feel free to scale your image to any sized tree.  For example, if the input was [0,1,2,3], your output might be:

```
Season 0:
_|_

Season 1:
 \
__|__

Season 2:
 _
  \| 
___|___

Season 3:

 |_/ _
   \| 
____|___
```

### Winner

Each solution must post the output of the coder's favorite run of their program with input of `[10,40]`, along with their source code.  Also, ALL the above criteria must be met in order to qualify.

**The winner will be the qualifier with the highest number of votes.**

Good luck and merry planting!!!

Comment: "Room to grow" doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: I think the tags "code-challenge" and "code-golf" do not fit together ("objective criterion other than code size" vs. "fewest bytes of source code").

Comment: @Peter Taylor:  To see if there is room to grow, you must first check the growth configurations for that branch type (e.g. vertical branches can go up-left, up, and up-right), and then see if any of those spaces are empty.  If so, there is room for growth.

Comment: @Howard: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing, but wasn't sure.  I think this is definitely more challenging than most problems I've seen on here, so I definitely wanted "code-challenge".  However, if there are multiple solutions, I wanted a way to determine a clear winner.  The scoring calculation above favors voting over atomic-code-golf scoring, so the atomic-code-golf score is really mainly a tie-breaker.  I'll leave it up to the people:  The golf requirements will be waved if Howard's comment gets more up-votes than this one.

Comment: With the present scoring mechanism, it isn't a [tag:code-golf]. It's not really a [tag:atomic-code-golf] either.

Comment: @Peter Taylor:  You and Howard are right.  I've simplified the winning criteria to pure votes and removed those tags so that people can be as creative as they want without worrying about golfing it.

Comment: @boothby: Yes, thanks for pointing that out.  Question updated.

Comment: Pure votes isn't really an *objective* criterion, though.

Comment: @Peter Taylor:  Currently, the objective criterion is "did you meet all the qualifications" and the tie-breaker is # of votes.  If you can think of a better way to judge the winner of this competition, I am definitely open to suggestions.

Comment: Some different ideas for this competition.  Develop your own growth algorithm (not random).  Grow a tree that maximizes total fruit production over a 50 year period.  Or grow the largest possible tree (defined by total characters) within a certain number of generations (fruit would thus be a liability because it impacts future growth).

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski:  Thanks for the suggestions, I especially like the fruit production over 50 year period one.  However, since there is already an answer, I don't think I should change the requirements to force that.  That said, people may feel free to take liberty with this as long as the above rules are met.  For example, maybe the starting intensity of light is n and the absorbtion rate is 1/n for each branch.  Maybe instead of growing a new branch in a random direction you can have it be deterministic.  Maybe a branch consumes a minimum amount of food for survival each season.  etc.

Comment: @Briguy37, if branches consumed a minimum amount of food each season, the trunk would break very quickly.

Comment: @boothby: True.  For that case we'd probably have to have a "Survival Mode" where lower branches can suck the nutrients they need from the upper branches.  This would be interesting with variable light intensities to represent the different seasons of the year, i.e. during "summer" where there is a lot of light the tree would outgrow what it could support during the "winter", and thus during the "winter" quite a few branches would die off.

Comment: Beautiful question!

Answer (score 16):

**Python**

I took a little liberty with this:

1. I allow multiple trees
2. Fruit is preceded by flower -- once a flower has 1 food, it turns into a fruit.
3. Fruit turns ripe when it has 3 food.  It then falls off of the tree, and turns back into a flower.
4. If fruit falls at least 4 places from any given trunk, it buds into a new tree.  Since it doesn't get much light, I seed it with as much food as was in the fruit.

**Sample Output, 2 trees**

```
                            / 
     \/\_ |  /             |  
 _  _/\|\|_\/             /|/ 
  |/ \/|/|O/              \|/ 
   \_/O|@|/               /|_ 
     \_|_|                \|  
_______|___________________|__

                       _      \                                   
                _/ _ \/\___/\|/                  \                
             /|\|\O@|/\/|__\/ \__/_\|/\\|  _ |/| _||/\\ /         
             \|_|@|\|@/O|@@/O_/@O|@/ \//\   \|\||@||@///          
           \_ \_|\|/@\\O|@||/OO//O\\O/ \@|@\||/@|\/\/|/   | / _   
        ___/    |/|/O//O|O||\\/|/O// \_O\|__| \O|/\/O|   _/\\|    
         / \_O@@_\/\O\\@|/O|/O\@\O\\@/OO/|O_@O/O|\/\/     \//|/__ 
     _|/|_|  \\|O\\/O/O||_@|\O|\/O//|O|@\|/O_O\@|/O/\_@O__//_||   
    | \\|____// |O|\O\O|/\@|/ |/O/ \|O|OO|\/@_/O|_O\/O//O_//O/    
    |_O\\@O\/\\OO\|/|/\O\O\|__@\|O@/|/O|O|/\OO\/|_O/  \\|OO\/     
   /  \\||_|\|||_O|\|@/OO\//OOO/|/@\|OO|\|\@|O \|\|O@O//  \/\     
 _/\_/@\|\@|/  \_||/ \\@|/\\\||/ \//O|O|/|/@|\@/|/O/OO\\__/  \||/ 
  \||/  |_|O\__@ |O\O/O||\///@|O_//|/OO|@|OO|/O\|O/OO|// /|\|/\|  
   ||___O@|_/  |__\/||_||/|\\/OO/|@|O|/ \|_O||_/O/O/O|/_|\/\|_/   
    \_OO\\_O\@_|/|_\|_O|/\|//\/|/@|O\|@_O|O_O\/||\/O/|/_|/|O|     
      \_|\@\@|_|\|OO|O|/\//O\/\O\@|_/|_@\|/\O/\||/\|/|@@|@|/      
       /|//|\|O|_|O\O\O\/|O\/|@|/_|\OO@\/ \/|O/_|O//@|@/\_|       
       \O\\|/|_OO|OO\O|/\|@@\|O|/ @//|_@\_/\|//O_/|O/  \/         
        \O\|O_/|/ \|O|O\/|/OO|O|O_/ \|    \/|/|/@ |/\__/          
         |O|_O\|\O/|_|O/\|\//|/   \_/     /\@\| \_/\/             
          \OO\O|/ \ _|@\/O||@|\___/       \/|/    \/              
           |__|O\__|OO\/\@||/\/            \|O____/               
              |____|/@/\|\|O\/            _/|/O                   
                   |/ \/|/|@/              \|/                    
                    \_/O|@|/              |/|__                   
            \|/       \_|_|  \|_      \|/  \|    \|/  _|_         
_____________|__________|_____|________|____|_____|____|__________
```

**Source**

```
from random import choice, shuffle
format = '_\|/_@O'
directions = [(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
placement = [[[],[0,1,2],[]],[[],[0,1,2],[3]],[[0,1],[2],[3,4]],[[1],[2,3,4],[]],[[],[2,3,4],[]]]

def shine():
    for x in ymax:
        light = 2.
        for y in range(ymax[x],-1,-1):
            if (x,y) in tree:
                tree[x,y][1] += light/2
                light        /= 2


def grow((x,y)=(0,0),flow=0):
    type,store,children = tree[x,y]
    food = store + flow
    if type == 5:
        if food > 1:
           tree[x,y][0] = 6
           tree[x,y][1] = food-1
        return
    elif type == 6:
        if food > 3:
            tree[x,y]=[5,0,[]]
            if min(abs(x-xi) for xi in roots) > 4:
                tree[x,0] = [2,food,[]]
                roots.append(x)
        else:
            tree[x,y][1]=food
        return

    if food < 1:
        shuffle(children)
        for c in children:
            grow(c)
        return

    sites = []
    x0 = x+directions[type][0]-1
    y0 = y+directions[type][1]
    for i,t in enumerate(placement[type]):
        if t and (x0+i,y0) not in tree:
            sites.append((t,x0+i,y0))

    if sites:
        t,x1,y1 = choice(sites)
        t1 = choice(t)
        children.append((x1,y1))
        tree[x,y][1]=food-1
        tree[x1,y1]= [t1,0,[]]
        ymax[x1] = max(ymax.get(x1,0),y1)
    elif children:
        shuffle(children)
        for c in children:
            grow(c,food/len(children))
        tree[x,y][1]=0
    else:
        tree[x,y][0]=5

def output():
    X = range(min(ymax.keys())-1,max(ymax.keys())+2)
    for y in range(max(ymax.values()),-1,-1):
        s = ''
        for x in X:
            s += format[tree[x,y][0]] if (x,y) in tree else '_ '[y>0]
        print s


roots = [0,20]
seasons = [10,40]
tree = {}
ymax = {}
for r in roots:
    tree[r,0] = [2,0,[]]
    ymax[r]=0

for season in range(max(seasons)):
    shine()
    shuffle(roots)
    for r in roots:
        grow((r,0))
    if season+1 in seasons:
        output()
        print
```

I'm curious to see a golfed solution.

Comment: I like the flowers turning into fruits and seeds idea!  One suggestion:  add a space rule to keep trees separate.  For example, maybe branches cannot sprout on any space adjacent to a branch from another tree.

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 673 chars

Here's a golfed version:

```
import random
Z='|_\/O'
T={60:0}
F={60:0}
C={60:[]}
B=[((1j-1,1),(1j-1,2),(1j,0),(1j+1,3),(1j+1,1)),((-1,1),(-1,2),(-1,0),(1,0),(1,3),(1,1)),((1j-1,1),(1j-1,2),(1\
j-1,0),(1j,3)),((1j,2),(1j+1,0),(1j+1,3),(1j+1,1)),()]
S=input()
for s in range(61):
 if s in S:
  for y in range(60,0,-1):print''.join(Z[T[x+y*1j]]if x+y*1j in T else' 'for x in range(121))
  print'_'*60+'|'+'_'*60
 for p in T:F[p]+=.5**sum(q.real==p.real and q.imag>p.imag and T[q]<4for q in T)
 for p in[q for q in T if F[q]>=1]:
  D=[p+d,c for d,c in B[T[p]]if p+d not in T]
  if D:q,c=random.choice(D);F[p]-=1;T[q]=c;F[q]=0;C[q]=[];C[p]+=[q]
  elif C[p]:
   for q in C[p]:F[q]+=F[p]/len(C[p])
  else:T[p]=4
```

sample @10 (truncated to the interesting part):

```
           |  |_   
       |_|/\_\ \|  
 |   \\/\|\/__|/   
 |/   \\O|O\__|    
  \___/O|/\/       
      \/O\/        
       \|/         
________|__________
```

sample @40:

```
             _  _        \_ _ / _|                        
        // _|/\|_\||_\___/ \_|_|/|/|_ |  _    //          
/     _|\\|_/\/|\/_/\/O|O\OO\|\|OO\|  \\/  |/|/|_/|       
\/\|OOO|//OO\O\|//OO/O_|O||\O|/|/|/OOO/ \OOO\/\| \||_|  | 
 \_|/|_O\\|\O\/|/O/O\_O|/  \\|O|O|/OO\\_/\O\|\/OO/\|O_|\| 
   |_|OO/O|/O/\|\/\O|O||_OOO|\\|/ \/O_|O\/OO|/O_|\/|OO|/  
     |/|\O|\|\/OO\O\|_|OO\|||// \OO\_O|O/  |||/_O/O|__|   
      \|O\O\|/\O\/\O|O|O\/O||/O_/|OO/\| \OO/\|/  \_|      
       |_/ O|\/O/\/\O\|\|\O|/\/OO|/ \/OO/\O\O\\__/        
         \_/O/\||/\O|\|O|O\\\/O_| \O/|/ \/O/_//     
           \O\/  \O\|_|O/\// \/OOOO|\|OO/|/|_|   
            |/\OO/O/  |O\/|\O/\O\|\O\|_|\|_|     
             \/OO\_\O__\|\|O|\/OO|/OO|___|       
              \|OOO\|O \\\|O|/|OO|OO\|          
               |/ \O|\_O\\|O|\|OO|O|/       
                \_/O|/O_//|O|/OO\|\|    
                  \_|OO \\O\|\/O_|/    
                    |/   \\O|O\__|    
                     \___/O|/\/     
                         \/O\/     
                          \|/    
___________________________|______________________________
```

Comment: Interesting... your tree looks very flat on top, whereas mine look rounded.   I wonder if one of us has a bug, or it's that I shuffle children to randomize what order they spawn grandchildren in.  Also, I notice that your fruit doesn't capture light... I wasn't sure if I should do that or not.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript

**UPD:** Added some new rules:

1. if branch can grow it become leaf at first, when leaf have >= 1 food it became a branch with food = leaf food
2. if branch have nowhere to grow and have food >= 1 food its turn into flower
3. if flower have more than 1.5 food it become a froot with flower food / 2
4. if froot have more than 1 food it drops on the ground and grows into new tree
5. each season have 10% chance to have rain which gives additional food to the branches on the ground which distributing food to the others.

Here is not the most beautiful code on javascript. May be later would be some improvements.
Code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atheo/7mhc7/)

```
var leaf = function(food, branchDirection){
    this.food = food || 0;
    this.branchDirection = branchDirection;
    this.char = 'o';

    this.getHtml = function(){
        var color = "#00FF00";
        var bgColor = "#00BBEE";

        return "<span style=\"color: " + color + "; background-color: " + bgColor + "\">" + this.char + "</span>";
    };
};

var branch = function(food, direction){
    var directionChars = ["_", "\\", "|", "/"];

    this.food = food || 0;
    this.char = directionChars[direction];
    this.direction = direction;
    this.child_branches = [];

    this.getPossibleDirections = function(){
        if(this.direction === 0)
        {
            return [
                    [-1, 0, [0,1,2]],
                    [+1, 0, [2,3,0]]
                ];
        }
        if(this.direction == 1)
        {
            return [
                    [-1, +1, [0,1,2]],
                    [0, +1, [3]]
                ];
        }
        if(this.direction == 2){
            return [
                    [-1, +1, [0,1]],
                    [0, +1, [2]],
                    [+1, +1, [3,0]]
                ];
        }
        if(this.direction == 3){
            return [
                    [+1 ,+1 , [0,2,3]],
                    [0 ,+1 , [1]]
                ];
        }
    };


    this.getHtml = function(){
        var color = "brown";
        var bgColor = "#00BBEE";

        return "<span style=\"color: " + color + "; background-color: " + bgColor + "\">" + this.char + "</span>";
    };
};

var froot = function(food){
    this.char = "O";
    this.food = food || 0;

    this.getHtml = function(){
        var color = "#FF0000";
        var bgColor = "#00BBEE";

        return "<span style=\"color: " + color + "; background-color: " + bgColor + "\">" + this.char + "</span>";
    }; 
};

var flower = function(food){
    this.char = "@";
    this.food = food || 0;

    this.getHtml = function(){
        var color = "#FFFF00";
        var bgColor = "#00BBEE";

        return "<span style=\"color: " + color + "; background-color: " + bgColor + "\">" + this.char + "</span>";
    };
};

var ground = function(){
    this.char = "_";

    this.getHtml = function(){
        var color = "black";
        var bgColor = "#00BBEE";

        return "<span style=\"color: " + color + "; background-color: " + bgColor + "\">" + this.char + "</span>";
    };
};

var air = function(){
    this.char = " ";

    this.getHtml = function(){
        var color = "blue";
        var bgColor = "#00BBEE";

        return "<span style=\"color: " + color + "; background-color: " + bgColor + "\">" + this.char + "</span>";
    };
};

var tree = function(){
    var me = this;
    var treeSpace = 5;


    this.treeMatrix = [];

    this.calculateFood = function(isRainy){
        //console.log(this.treeMatrix);
        var width = this.treeMatrix[0].length;
        isRainy = isRainy || false;

        for(var i in this.treeMatrix[0]){
            var food = 2;

            for(var j in this.treeMatrix){
                if(this.treeMatrix[this.treeMatrix.length - 1 - j][i] instanceof branch
                  || this.treeMatrix[this.treeMatrix.length - 1 - j][i] instanceof leaf){
                    this.treeMatrix[this.treeMatrix.length -1 - j][i].food += food;
                    food /= 2;
                }
            }

            if(isRainy){
                var rainFood = 5;

                for(var j in this.treeMatrix){
                    if(j == 0 && !(this.treeMatrix[j][i] instanceof branch))
                        continue;

                    if((this.treeMatrix[j][i] instanceof branch
                      || this.treeMatrix[j][i] instanceof leaf)
                      &&
                      (j == 0 || this.treeMatrix[j-1][i] instanceof branch)){
                        this.treeMatrix[j][i].food += food;
                        rainFood /= 2;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    };

    this.expandMatrix = function(){
        var expandLeft = false;
        var expandRight = false;
        var expandTop = false;

        this.treeMatrix[this.treeMatrix.length - 1].forEach(function(el){
            if(el instanceof branch)
                expandTop = true;
        });

        if(expandTop)
            this.treeMatrix.push(this.treeMatrix[0].map(function(){return new air();}));


        for(var i in this.treeMatrix){
            if(this.treeMatrix[i][0] instanceof branch){
                expandLeft = true;
            }
            if(this.treeMatrix[i][this.treeMatrix.length - 1] instanceof branch){
                expandRight = true;
            }
        }

        this.treeMatrix = this.treeMatrix.map(function(row){
            if(expandLeft)
                row.unshift((row[0] instanceof ground ? new ground() : new air()));
            if(expandRight)
                row.push((row[0] instanceof ground ? new ground() : new air()));

            return row;
        });
    };

    this.calculateNewMatrix = function(){
        if(this.treeMatrix.length === 0){
            this.treeMatrix.push([new ground(), new branch(0,2), new ground()]);
        }

        var rainySeason = Math.random() > 0.9;

        this.expandMatrix();
        this.calculateFood(rainySeason);

        for(var i in this.treeMatrix){
            for(var j in this.treeMatrix[i]){
                var element = this.treeMatrix[i][j];

                // grow a branch/distribute food/set froot or just store food of not(do nothing)
                if(element instanceof branch
                    && element.food >= 1
                ){
                    //console.log("branch coordinates", i, j);
                    var directions = element.getPossibleDirections();
                    var tm = this.treeMatrix;

                    var freeDirections = directions.filter(function(directionArr){
                        if(tm[parseInt(i) + directionArr[1]][parseInt(j) + directionArr[0]] instanceof branch)
                            return false;
                        else
                            return true;
                    });

                    if(freeDirections.length){
                        var newCell = freeDirections.length > 1
                            ? freeDirections[Math.floor(Math.random() * freeDirections.length)]
                            : freeDirections[0];

                        this.treeMatrix[parseInt(i) + newCell[1]][parseInt(j) + newCell[0]] = new leaf(element.food/2, newCell[2][Math.floor(Math.random() * newCell[2].length)]);
                        element.child_branches.push(this.treeMatrix[parseInt(i) + newCell[1]][parseInt(j) + newCell[0]]);
                    }
                    else if(!freeDirections.length && !element.child_branches.length){
                        this.treeMatrix[i][j] = new flower(element.food/2);
                    }
                    else if(!freeDirections.length && element.child_branches.length){
                        element.child_branches.forEach(function(child){
                            child.food += element.food/element.child_branches.length;
                        });

                        element.food = 0;
                    }
                }
                if(element instanceof flower
                    && element.food >= 1.5
                  ){
                    this.treeMatrix[i][j] = new froot(element.food/2);
                }
                if(element instanceof froot
                    && element.food >= 1
                  ){
                    this.plantNewTree(j, element.food);
                    this.treeMatrix[i][j] = new air();
                }
                if(element instanceof leaf
                    && element.food >= 1
                  ){
                   this.treeMatrix[i][j] = new branch(element.food, element.branchDirection);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    this.plantNewTree = function(coord, food){
        var canGrow = true;

        for(var i = 0; i <= treeSpace; i++){
            if(!(this.treeMatrix[0][coord + i] instanceof ground)
               || !(this.treeMatrix[0][coord - i] instanceof ground))
                canGrow = false;
        }

        if(canGrow)
            this.treeMatrix[0][coord] = new branch(food*10, 2);
    };

    this.getTreeString = function(){
        return this.treeMatrix.reduceRight(function(prev, next){
                return (
                typeof prev == "string"
                    ? prev
                    : prev.map(function(el){ return el.char}).join('')
                ) + "\n" + next.map(function(el){ return el.char}).join('');
                 })
    };

    this.getTreeHtml = function(){
        return "<pre>" + this.treeMatrix.reduceRight(function(prev, next){
                return (
                typeof prev == "string"
                    ? prev
                    : prev.map(function(el){ return el.getHtml()}).join('')
                ) + "<br/>" + next.map(function(el){ return el.getHtml()}).join('');
                 }) + "</pre>";
    };
};


var seasonsTotal = 300;
var seasonsCounter = 0;
var showAt = [1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,300];
var pageTree = new tree();

var season = function(){
    pageTree.calculateNewMatrix();
    seasonsCounter++;
    if(showAt.indexOf(seasonsCounter) >= 0){console.log(pageTree.getTreeString()); document.body.innerHTML = pageTree.getTreeHtml();}
};

window.onload = function(){
        var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
                season();
                if(seasonsCounter >= seasonsTotal)
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                }, 100);
};
```

Some examples(10,40,100):

```
           \/          
        \ |/\_/_       
      |  \/\/|/0/_ _   
      |/  \/0||/|_//   
     / \0_/0/\|0|_|    
     \_/00\0\/|_|      
       \_|/00\|        
         |__|/         
    ________|__________


     /           
   _ \_          
    |/\o_| /     
o_/  \/ @|/\|    
_@\o__\_/|o/     
 \|\|\/ \|/      
  |/  \_//       
   \__/_|        
______|__________



                       \ \/\                                      
                 \    |/\/\_|/ |   |  /                           
              \ \@\/ \/\/\/ |/  \_/ \||_                          
          _  _\\/@/\/@\/\/   \_//\__/|/\_                         
           \ /\|\/|/|_o\/  __/o|\/_|_/\/__|                       
          |@|\_|/_o\|/\|\__o/\\|/\_|\|//|/\__|                    
       |_||/|_@|\/|\|_/|/|| \/ |\//\/o\\\\_@\|| |_|               
       |/|/\|_||/\o\|/_/\/\_/\o|/ \/|_//// \/ \\|                 
     __@\|\||/\|@/|/o\/\/\/_@_\|\_/\_/|/ \_/__//                  
     __\/|/_@\O|o\|@|@\/\/\_|o/|/|\|\/|_//_||_/                   
  \ \ \|\|_/\|\|//|/\|_\/\//_@\/\|/|/\||//|\|o                    
 / |/ _|_|@|/|/ \\|__|_o\/o\\|o\||\|\/O|/O|/o_|_|                 
 \_/\|___|_|  \_/_|\/ \\/@|\\|\/||/|/\_|__|@|\|___/ /             
|_||/|_@_\@\o_/o|o|/@_/\\/_//o \|/\|\/@|_o__|_|__/|/              
  |@\| /|/\_\|\|/\||_/\_|\@|\\_/|\/@/|/|__/O|_/_/_|/              
   \||@\|_@_\|/|\@|//o\||//o\||\|/\/||||o___|/ @|_|  _            
    |o\/ \|@@|/ /\O\\/\|o\\|/o|/ \/|/\/\/|\@/\_/|/\_/             
     \|\o/ \/ \ \/o_|\/|\//|\/o\_/_|O/\//o_|\/@//\/               
      \\|\_@\_/_o\_/|o\|/|_|_\|/O|/|/\|||__|/o \\/                
       \|/_|@\\/\\_\|/\|\|@\|\|\_|\|O//O/o_/ \_//                 
        |_@|_/@\/_/\|@_|//o/_/o//@\|/|\//||____|                  
 o_______\\/\\|@\/\/__@\\\/|_o/|__|\\|/|/O|                       
         \|\/ |_o\/\o|_////_/|\|_|@/@|_|\/                        
          |_\_o\\/\/\o\|/|/ O|/ O|/\/\|\/                         
            \||/@\/\O\_|\|@_/ \_/|O/@_|/                          
             |_\|_\O|/o|/ oo\_/@/  \__|                           
               \|_\|\\_|\_/_|/\|___/                              
                |/\| \||/ |_|\/|/                                 
                 \ |_/@ \/ o|/\|                                  
                  |_o\\_@\_/|@/                                   
                    \|\|\/ \|/                                    
                     |/  \_//                                     
                      \__/_|                                      
______|__________________|________________________________________



                                                     |                                                                                                            
                                                  \  /\_       \/   |      _    \                                                                                 
                                                 |/ |\/_/\  |_\/\|_/\  _\ /  \  |\/\  |                                                                           
                                              / /_\_|/|__/\/|_|\/_/\/\_|\|\ \ \\|/_/|/\ \    _                                                                    
                                            _|_//|/ |/__|\/\@\\/|/o/|//\/_/_/@/@|\|\@\/\/_ \/ __                                                                  
                                   \      \|\|o\\|\o/\/O /\|\/|\O\|_|/_///|@\|\\|/|/@|\/\_|@\|/\\|                                                                
                                _ \/\_o_\_/|/ \\\|/|\/ \O\/_@\/\|/|/|_/\\\|_/ \\|\|o_|_\|\|\/|\/\|_|\  /                                                          
                              \o_\|\|\_|||\/\_/o\|o|/\_/__\/\/\/\\|o_@\///  \o/o|/|__|\o|/||||/\/|O|/|@\/                                                         
                              \|@/|/@\|\/\/o/@\|\|_o\/_/||/\/\o\/O|/|@_\\\__/ \/|\__/|//|\/\|/\/o||@\/\/__|                                                       
                               |O\O\|\|/o//o\//|//\|/|o/|O\|\|\|\_|@|/ \\|||\_/\|///O|// @\/O\/|/\\\/\\\/\__|                                                     
                                \||/@/|\/\\/|\\o\\ |/|/\|@\|O|/|/ |_|__//_||O\|o|//o_|\\_//\_|\|\/_||//|\/@\|\                                                    
                         |   \__@|/\/\|/_/|\|_\|/\\/\/\/| \|_@\/\_|o|/\|_o||o/\\|/@/_o//\@\/\|/|/\o\|\\|/ \/|/                                                    
                      o_\|/   \|||\/\||_/\|/|@\|\/\\/\/\|_/|o_|\/o/\o\/|_|/\o\/ \\/|_|/\/_@\/| |__|/|//O\_///\o_                                                  
                        \|\|o_/@|\\\||/\|\|o|_@|/o/O\/\_|_/_o_|O\|_/\@\||/  |/\ /|\_/|O/o/|/\|o|/|/\| \|/@/|_/|_|\ _                                              
                  / /\__/|/o__\_|_|\|/\/\/|/|/|_\|\/ \/\|/\@|__o||\|/o_|/\__/\/ \|/@/||o/| \/|_@\|_/___|O|_|@/|_@/|//                                             
                  \/\o_/\| o__|\|@|/\\o\/\|\|_@/\|/_o/o/o\/\\/\\||/|\__|\/|/_/__/ \/\|@\\|\/ @/\/ \|o_/\_|\/o\|  \|/\\                                            
                o_/\/|@\/  _/o|\|\/\/O\/\//\| \\/o\\|\/o_|\/@\o\||\|/O\|\\o\_|@|\_/\_|_/||/@_/_/\_/_/__/@@/|\/\__/|o//                                            
                  \o\|_@\___|/\\|_\/\o|\//\/o_/@\|/@|/  \|/o\|\/\@\|\o\|//@/@|/\/o\/o/OO|/\_/\o\//|o/|/|_/\|/O__o\|/ \__\                                         
             \     |\|__/  \/\/\|_||/\|/|\/   \|/|o_|\__/O\\_|/_/o/|/\/ \\|\\/\/o\/\/\\_|\/ \/_|\\| \|_| \/|//  \/|_o/\__\__                                      
          |   |/ o_o\| o\\_/|@\/ o|/\_|\|@\_o_/|\|/@\/\\_@|\\|/o_/||_/\o//|_|\/__|\/\/ /|/O_/\/\//__/|___/_|@\_o/O|o/@/ \/|_                                      
         \|/o_@\_/|\||_//@_\|_/@__|\/o|/_/\||/| \|_/_\//@\|//o\_o\||/\//\\|_ //_|o/\/\o\|_o\\|\/// @_|\_||@_|/@|\/_/\/\_/_| /                                     
          |\_/|/_|\\|@ \\|o\|o\_o_|@\\|/O_//\\|_o|/\_||_|/| \\/o\/|O\/\\//_/|o\O\/\/|/|/@||//|//@\__/\|__|/\/ \|/|_|/__/||\|                                      
        /_/\|\/\||/ |__@\|/o|_/_|_|\@\|\/  \/ |/_|\/_||o|/|_//\_|\|_|\/O\\/\|o/o/@|\|_|_/o_\\o\\|/_@__|_||\|\_/ \|@|\@|//\\||                                     
        \|\@|/\/\_\_o\|o|\\\|_|o|/\O\_|/\o_/| |_/|/ o\|_|\|o/\/_o/o|\/o_\|\/ |_/\_|/|_||\_O\||/\|\_|@_|__o\|/_@_/__|/\|/\// |//                                   
      o_\|@\|_@\//|\_/_|\\|\|\_@\\/_//\\|\|\|_@_\|\o/o|\|o|/\/O\|/@|O\_/\|/\_@\|/_|\|O||/@_/@/\/o//o__||O\/@\|\/\_||\/o\/ \_|/  _                                 
       _\|_/|\|/\\ \|\O|/o\\|\||/o\/|oo\|/|@|_|_/o/ \\|/|_|\/|/O|\||\@\|/ \/||/|/o\/o_| \o_\|_/O|/@/_@/|_/_|_|/\/o\|/|_/\\/@|\_|                                  
     o__|\o\|_|\@||/|@|/\|/@|/o|\_|\_\|/|/ \@\|/\/\o|\|\|/|/\|\/|_| \\|\\_/\||_|_|/\@\\_//@_\|\||_/|_|O/\|O|\/|/  \|   \_||_|/\                                   
        |/_||o|_||\\|_|\/|\|o\/_/ |/ \|_|__/_//\o\/_|\|/|@ \/_/\||__/ |/_|\/|/\|o|_||//@/\_o\|/@|/@|/@/\/_/_o\|__o/o___/|_|_|o_|                                  
    _ \oo\/\/\|o||\||/|@\|/_/ \o\_@\_/|/|/\|/|\@\|\_|\|/|_o/\_|_|| \__|\||o\|\/_/|_/|/_/_/_@_|@/|\/|_/\//@/o\/ \\/\/ o__|_| @/__o                                 
    /\/@|\\/oo|/@|_|\\|\\|\\\_/\|\|/\\o\\\/o\|/\/|///\|\/\|o/\/  |_@_\\/|O\/|/|///|\|@_|\\@|/\/_|/\|o_//o/\|\\_//\/\_/O|/o__/\_|                                  
    \/\_|/o\/\\\/|O\/||_||//@_\_|/o\/@|/@\\//\\/|o\\\/@_\/_/\|\_/|_|_//\|\/\|\|\\\|/||\_//o|\//|O\/O|\||O\/_//O|o/\/O|_|o_|@\/                                    
     \O_|\_|\/\|\|_o\|_/|@\\|__|\\|/\/_\|/|\\o|\|\/@|\__|\/\/ \|\|o|//\/o \O\\|//_|\||/o_\/|/\\|//\_|_||_/\_|\||O\/\_|@/|_|_/                                     
      |_|/_|@\_|_||_O||\|\\||@||/@|\/_|\|\|_|\|/|o\/|/o/|/|/O/o|/ \||\/\\_/_//|/@|\/O|o__|\o\//| \/|/__|o_/\_//@|/ /@@|\__|                                       
     o  |\_|_|_|O|/o/|o\|/ \\\|\\/|/_/\||o|o\\\\o\/\|_/\O\\\/ o|\_//O/\/|\|@|_o\_|/\_|/\\_/\/\\|_/O||/\_||@/_@\/|o|/\_||\/                                        
      |_@\||o|_/\|\/\|\/ \_||\|\|\\\O\o||/o\/ \|\|\//@_/O_\|\_/|/o|_o\ \|/|_|o//_o\/_@\_|||/O//|/|\||_/ \|// |/O|//|/|/|/                                         
       o\_|/\\@\/| \/|@\__|\o\|_|/ ||/o|o\/\\_o|/\@\\_/\_o\|/ \|/_| \|\//\|/|/o\_|/|@|o|\|o\|/\|/|/o|/\_/|\\_|/O|@\|\/\|                                          
       o|o|o@\|o\|oo\|\/ \\/|_|_|\_@\\/__|\/_|\|_/_/|\_//\\|\_/\\/|_/  \\/|\|/\/o/\|_|o|/|_//\//O|//o\/|/@o|\|_/o \|/ /                                           
 \_____/\|/\|O|/o\\\||/\_o|\|||/|@\|\|\/\_/o\|//@\|\|/\|o/o|/__//\|@o__//o|\|O/\//_|o|_@\|/|_//\_| \\ \||O/|_|  \_/|\/                                            
 o\|\_||_|__|_o\/o\||o\\||O\|/\\|\O|/\/ / \|/ \\_\|O|_/@|\|\\_\/\/_\_o|\\/\/@_\/\\/|o|/// \|@/\/o\| \|/o|_\| @__/@_|/oo                                           
 /||@\\ _|\@|/  \_||_\/|||o/@\/_|/\ \ \|_o/|\o_|\||_|o__| |/@_\\/__||_/\\\|\__|\//\|_|/\\_/@|_/\/||/\||_|_/__/  \__|o/                                            
 \/\\/ |@|_| \ _/@_| \\|/\/\_|\\\\/\_|O|_/\|/_@|/o__|//__/|/|_//|_|_| \o\||/o/|/@\\|/|_///@/|/\/_||_//_||@|_@___/@__|                                             
  \_|\_/\oo|_/_@\_@\_@\|@/ /o\/@\|\_ \\||_/|o|\@\_/|/ \|\_|_@_\\/\|@__/\/_o\|/|O//_|\|@/||/|@\/\/|/\||@/@/|__|_@//|/                                              
    |__\|\|_o\/\/_|\|\O|/\o\_|\|_|_/| \|o|\|o|/\_o\|\__|/o/_|_o\\/_/|\| \ |//o|/ \|\/|//\|@\\|\/_|\/_|/\/\|/o@/|/_|                                               
       \|_||/ \/\_|_|/o|\/|/ \\|o|_||_/o/  |/ \/ |_|//o|\/_@\/\//  \|_|_/o||/\|\_/@_\|\\_|_/_|/|o\//O///\_|/  \|/                                                 
        |_\|\_o\/O|o|_\|@\o\_o\|/|_|_@\|\@_/\_/___o|\\_| \/\o\/ \_@_|@|/ \||_/|/@__O\|//O|_||O\|_||\/ \\/o \__/|                                                  
          \|/|\|\|/\\\||\/||\|_|\_O|__/|/ |\__\@|\_o\|\\_/_/_/o_/\/\|_@\_@|/\_|__|\|@|/|_|| |_/|_@|/\_//o\_/ O/                                                   
           \\|/  |_// |/\\||O|_|o_|\\o\|\o|/__\||o\|\|/o\\||/\_/\/\_|_|\\|||/@|_o/\|/|_||/_o/\_|@\/\/_||\_@\_/                                                    
            \|o___o|_o_\//o|_/\\_||\||@|/|\\_@\|/\/@/|\/|||o\/o//\//|o_///O|\/|/o\o|/|_||__|\/|__|\/|/o|/ \/                                                      
             |\|@_\O \|\\\/_@\/_\\|_|/\o\|_|\_/@\o\/  \\| \\/\|\\/ \|/\|\\_|/_|_/_||/|O/|/o|/\|_||/\| \/\_/                                                       
              \|/  \__|_||\/\/O|\\|_|o/\/|/@\_\|/|/\_o/ |o_|\/|/ \_/o\_|/|\|__|@_/\|/O/_o\/ \o|__|\/  o\/                                                         
               |_____o|_|@\\/_o\\|\@\|\/\|\// \|\|\/_|\_/\|\/\ \_/@_|/o|/ \|____/\//\/|o_/   \|/|_/o__//                                                          
                 oooo|_/|@|\\||\||/|/|\\//|\\_o|/|/\/\/\|o|/o/o/@_|||o\|\o/ \|O/o/\\|\|_o\___/|O|oo/ \|                                                           
               o__|/\|o\|/|_||/\|/\|_@\|\\|/@\\|\|\|\/o/|_|\/\/\|\_|\\\|/ \_/  \|\/O|/|_|/|_//|/_//__/oo                                                          
                  |_//  |_|\//@/ \ |__@|O||\//@|_|/|/\/\|o|/\/\_|/||/ \|o_/Oo__/_/\/|\|/|\|/ \|@_|/ooo|                                                           
                    |_____|//@|\_/\|O|_/\||/ \/ \\\/\O\/o\/\/\/ |/ o\_/ \||_/ \| \@\|\|\|/|__/___|/|_/                                                            
                       ooo|/ \|@\\_|o_@\/_|@_/__/_\\/o/\/o\/\/o  \_//\__/|/\__/__/_o|/|_|_|__|oooo\|                                                              
                     o__|/o\__|_//@|/\\o\o\_o\|\\O\|\/|/|_|\/|___/@|\/_|_/\/__|o_@_||\|_|@/ oo\\/\/                                                               
                        |_|\\||@|\|@\/|\\|o|\\|o|\_|/_o\|/\|\__@/\\|/\_|\|//O/|__|/_|/|__|oo \/ \/                                                                
                          |/ ||_|/|_@\|/\|\|_||/|_@|\/|\|_/|/|| \/o|\//\/o\\\\_o\||o|_|oo_|__@\_/                                                                 
                           \_o\\|@|_|_|O/  |/|@\|_||/\o\|/_/\/\_/\o|/ \/|_//// \/ O\| oo\/|/@|/oo                                                                 
                             \_||@|__@| \__@\|\O|/_|@/|/o\/\/\/_@_\|\_/\_/|/o\_/__// oo|/\|\_|@|_oo                                                               
                               |/\\_\_|_@_|\/|/_@\\|o\|@|@\/\/\_|o/|/|\|\/|_//_||_/ooo\|\_|/o_/|_|                                                                
                                \@|@|\\|\|\|\|_/\|\|//|/\|_\/\//_@\/\|/|/\||//|\|@|_|//|/O|o_/\|                                                                  
                                 \|\|/ |/|@|_|@|_|/ \\|__|_o\/o\\|o\||\|\/O|/O|/@_|_| \/\/_o_\/                                                                   
                                  |_|\_/\|O__|_|  \_/_|\/ \\/@|\\|\/||/|/\_|__|@|\|___/\/|\|_/                                                                    
                                    |_||/|_@_\@\o_/o|o|/@_/\\/_//o \|/\|\/@|_o__|_|__/|/||/|/                                                                     
                                      |o\| /|/\_\|\|/\||_/\_|\@|\\_/|\/@/|/|__/O|_/_/_|// \|                                                                      
                                       \||@\|_@_\|/|\@|//o\||//o\||\|/\/||||o___|/o_|@| \_/                                                                       
                                        |o\/ \|@@|/ /\O\\/\|o\\|/o|/ \/|/\/\/|_o/\_/|/\_/                                                                         
                                         \|\o/ \/ \ \/o_|\/|\//|\/o\_/_|O/\//o_|\/@//\/                                                                           
                                          \\|\_@\_/_o\_/|o\|/|_|_\|/O|/|/\|||__|/o \\/                                                                            
                                           \|/_|@\\/\\_\|/\|\|@\|\|\_|\|O//O/o_/ \_//                                                                             
                                            |_@|_/@\/_/\|@_|//o/_/o//@\|/|\//||____|                                                                              
                                    o________\\/\\|@\/\/__@\\\/|_o/|__|\\|/|/O|                                                                                   
                                             \|\/ |_o\/\o|_////_/|\|_|@/@|_|\/                                                                                    
                                              |_\_o\\/\/\o\|/|/ O|/ O|/\/\|\/                                                                                     
                                                \||/@\/\O\_|\|@_/ \_/|O/@_|/                                                                                      
                                                 |_\|_\O|/o|/ oo\_/@/  \__|                                                                                       
                                                   \|_\|\\_|\_/_|/\|___/                                                                                          
                                                    |/\| \||/ |_|\/|/                                                                                             
                                                     \ |_/@ \/ o|/\|                                                                                              
               oooooooo  ooo           oo             |_o\\_@\_/|@/                                                                                               
              oo|_o\|/oo__|_oo        o_\_o_oo          \|\|\/ \|/                                                                                                
               |/\|/|  \/\|/|_o         |\|_/            |/  \_//                                                                                                 
                \_|/    \_|_|            \|/              \__/_|                                                                                                  
__________________|_______|_______________|__________________|____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```